# Clearing custom normals not working as expected in add-on

Tags: python, add-on

I have a button in an add-on that is supposed to loop through your selected objects and clear custom split normals data, among other common mesh cleanup tasks. This code works perfectly fine in a standard Python script:

```
import bpy

selection = bpy.context.selected_objects
for obj in selection:
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_clear()
```

But the same code does not work in the context of the add-on.

```
class ClearNormal(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.clear_normal"
    bl_label = "ClearNormal"

    def execute(self, context):
        selection = bpy.context.selected_objects
        
        for obj in selection:
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
            bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_clear()

            return {"FINISHED"}
```

Note: This question was originally posted by wayland in blenderartists.org
https://blenderartists.org/t/clearing-custom-normals-not-working-as-expected-in-add-on/1269404

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a more complete example please? The way the question is asked now, anyone who wants to give it a shot needs to create the rest of the code himself (bl_info, registering the operator, providing a UI button to call it, etc.). You might reach more people to try an answer this way. Also, is this operator on your side called from within a 3D ViewPort, or from the command line? This is important because `bpy.context` differs per area it is called from.

Comment: Thanks mate I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to how Python uses offset to group operators. Python doesn't take into account blank lines, instead the offset of lines is used for grouping. `return {"FINISHED"}` has the same offset as 2 lines of code before. So after first iteration Python goes to `return` end stop the cycle.

```
    for obj in selection:
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_clear()

        # will be executed in the first loop:
        return {"FINISHED"}
```

To fix that, use right offset:

```
    for obj in selection:
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_clear()

    # will be executed after all loop iterations:
    return {"FINISHED"}
```

Comment: I am stupid. Thank you man.